# Prove: $m$ can be written as a sum of $2k + 1$ consecutive integers implies $2k + 1 \mid m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, divisibility, integers

Prove that for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and odd $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that:

$$
m \text{ can be written as a sum of $n$ consecutive integers} \Rightarrow n \mid m 
$$

I was able to prove the statement above, but my proof needs different cases.

Sketch of proof:
If $m$ can be written as a sum of $n$ consecutive integers there exists $j \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $n = \sum_{i=j}^{j+n-1}I$.

Now I differentiate between the cases $(j \geq 0), (j < 0 \text{ and } j + n-1 \geq 0)$ and ($j < 0 \text{ and } j + n - 1 < 0$).

In the first two cases I write the sum for $n$ as two sums starting at $0$ and using triangular numbers to find an explicit description, where I can luckily put $n$ outside the brackets. The third case can be transformed into the first case (via first case $n \mid -m \Rightarrow n\mid m$).

This proof is working, but I guess that there is an easier way not involving different cases. Any help is welcome :)

Comment: The result in your title and the result in your question are different. Which is it you're asking about?

Comment: @Shaun They are not different. $2k + 1$ is an odd integer $n$.

Comment: Yes, they are; one is about *consecutive* integers.

Comment: @Shaun Oh, you are right. I missed that. Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that $m$ can be written as$$a+(a+1)+\cdots+(a+2k),\tag{1}$$for some $k$. Note that\begin{align}(1)&=(2k+1)a+\sum_{j=0}^{2k}j\\&=(2k+1)a+\frac{2k(2k+1)}2\\&=(2k+1)(a+k).\end{align}Therefore, $2k+1\mid m$.

Comment: How does this imply $n \mid m$? Also (1) is a sum of $2k + 1$ integers not $n$ integers (as it should be).

Comment: @user7802048 But we are assuming that $n$ is odd. Therefore, it can be written as $2k+1$.

Comment: I see. Very nice solution :)

Answer (score 1):

m = i + (i+1) + (i+2) + ... + j, a sum of n terms.

Therefore n can be written as : number of terms x average of i and j.

m = (i+j)/2 * n

The sum of i and j is even because n is odd (i and j are either both even or both odd). Thus n divides m.

edit:no i won't use mathjax for such simple expressions.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).